# Resize image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to resize my default theme image slider and was unable to resize the window to a specific size. Can anyone please tell me what additions i need to do to this code in order to resize the slider width and height?

Comment: _"Can anyone please tell me what additions i need to do to this code in order to resize the slider width and height?"_ No code appears at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

if you want to crop image to your desire size then use below code in your functions.php file

```
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
```

and get this image.

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $name );
```

or if you want resize image with proper aspect ratio, then use this function, may be it will help u.

```
 function resize ($width, $height ){
    /* Get original image x y*/
    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    /* calculate new image size with ratio */
    $ratio = max( $width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
    /* new file name */
    $path = 'uploads/'.$width.'x'.$height.'_'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
    /* read binary data from image file */
    $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    /* create image from string */
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);
    /* Save image */
    switch ($_FILES['image']['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($tmp, $path, 0);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($tmp, $path);
            break;
        default:
            exit;
            break;
    }
    return $path;
    /* cleanup memory */
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

i resize my image with this function in my project.